# OBIEE Projection Calculations by Month

Tags: obiee

If I have a single value in say December of last year. How do I make it appear in each month, so that I can do running projections based on it?

Ex. 
                                       JAN FEB MAR
PYE
Current
Prior 
Proj ((Curr-Prior)/Prior) * PYE)

I can write a formula to hard code month and have in my column calculations for each month but I am searching for a solution that is more dynamic. So, I can drag in month as a value and do rolling 6 month calculations without updating columns.

I can also use a max function and that makes it appear correctly but when I slice it by any field besides the month. The max breaks down and gives me the max split and not the max overall that is split.

Also, I would prefer to do it without a time hierarchy and AGO.

Thank you!

Comment: your requirement is not very clear. Please elaborate on what you mean by "make it appear in each month, so that I can do running projections based on it".

Are you looking for "Year-To-Date" calculations? In that case, you could use these date calculations here:  http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/function_time   ...   or here:  http://shahin-obiee.blogspot.in/2012/04/various-calculations-for-date_16.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. My PYE is a YTD taken in Dec-16. I would like that YTD from value to appear in all current periods even though that it "tied" to Dec-16.  I would like that value to appear JAN-17 and FEB-17 so I can do comparisons of projections.  For instance, if I ended 16 with a ytd value of 1000. I would like that 1000 to appear in JAN-17 as 1000 PYE. I would like to create a metric column I can drop in that is PYE in a month spread for 17. The only way that I know to that is use AGO and offset by month (using a formula that you listed above) but I would prefer an alt.

Comment: The way I have been able to accomplish this so far is I create a column for each month of my projection. a Jan column a Feb column and so on and I hard code the exact month for each in the column formula. i.e. I calculate the pye value and multiply  by my calculations from the current month for each month. That way OBIEE doesn't have any specific reference at the analysis level but what I would like to do is have the PYE appear in each of the months if I drop in a month column -that would make it so much easier. I can accomplish this with max() for 16 but if I do that then I can't slice it.

Comment: please update your question with the relevant details that you've added in the comments.

Comment: I think you may be looking for a pivot measure. Tell me if I'm right.
The value will be dynamic and between the given range defined in your pivot measure. http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/filter_function
you could use these date calculations here in your Filter function: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/function_time ... or here: http://shahin-obiee.blogspot.in/2012/04/various-calculations-for-date_16.html